# finding lines in a file matching patterns defined in another file

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files `file1.txt`

```
kepaul
jack
mike 
david
```

and `file2.txt`

```
1 london smith 12564
2 miami jack 51616
3 la mike 165156
4 london kepaul 54654
5 miami grag 46546
```

and I need to print to a new file lines from `file2.txt` containing names found in `file1.txt` names. So my result should be

```
4 london kepaul 54654
2 miami jack 51616
3 la mike 165156
```

Comment: The subject is much more efficient now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use grep for this?  If so, you could do it with

```
grep -Ff file1.txt file2.txt
```

to read the patterns from `file1.txt` and match them from `file2.txt`